# Use Rhino Mocks to create an in-memory database for use while developing code and user interface

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, repository, rhino-mocks

I've been struggling with this all morning and I may be completely on the wrong track since Rhino Mocks was originally designed for Unit Testing.

However, I have a couple of resusable backend components that handle Authentication and 'Blogging' like features of a website, each contains their own data access layer.  While developing the user interface, I really don't want to be messing around with creating test data in a database and / or an XML file.

What I'm striving for is an implementation of my data access interfaces (IBlogRepository), for example to run as singletons throughout the lifetime of a debugging session (aka an in-memory database) so that I can display some data to design against.

Hope that makes sense!  All comments greatly appreciated.

Jason

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a mock, actually create a test implementation of your `IBlogRepository` interface, which returns hard-coded dummy data.

Comment: Hi David, this was my backup plan from the start.  It just would have been nice to save a bit of time by getting rhinomocks to create a load of dummy data for me!  Thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Comment: Take a look at NBuilder by the way - will help if you want to create a lot of data.

Answer (score 2):

Singletons are at odds with Testability because they are so hard to change. You would be much better off using **Dependency Injection** to inject an IBlogRepository instance into your consuming classes:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IBlogRepository repository;

    public MyClass(IBlogRepository repository)
    {
        if(repository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        }

        this.repository = repository;
    }

    // use this.repository in other members
}
```

Notice how the Guard Claus together with the `readonly` keyword guarantees that the IBlogRepository instance will always be available.

This will allow you to use Rhino Mocks or another dynamic mock library to inject [Test Doubles](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Double.html) of IBlogRepository into the consuming classes.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm actually using structuremap for dependency injection in all my layers.  I totally agree with what you've said.  What I'm trying to do is dynamically create an implementation of said Interface at application runtime so that I can see some dummy data displayed on the page while I'm designing the UI.
I think I'm more than likely going to go with David's response below though as it definately appears easier!  Thanks for taking the time to reply :)

Comment: Yes, what you are talking about then is a sort of Integration Testing where you want to replace the lowest layer with a Test Double. In such cases, a Fake as suggested by David M is the best option, although it may require significantly more effort - and then you may ask yourself why you don't use the real IBlogRepository implementation instead, and turn your Integration Test into a System Test?